# Working with Fluent API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Following is my db context I have overridden the method called `OnModelCreating` for using `Fluent API`. When I build solution I get no error but schema also remains unchanged.

```
public class BreakAwayContext : DbContext
    {
        public BreakAwayContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BreakAwayContext>());
        }
        public DbSet<Destination> Destinations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Destination>().Property(d => d.Name).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Destination>().Property(d => d.Description).HasMaxLength(600);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Destination>().Property(d => d.Photo).HasColumnType("image");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Lodging>().Property(l => l.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(200);
        }

    }
```

Here is a screen shot showing unchanged length for `Description` column.

[image]

Do I need to `Add-Migration` or `Update-Database` after overriding above mentioned method?

Comment: have you used the db context after adding the model creating?

Comment: As you said try to update the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved. I had to use `Add-Migration` followed by `Update-Database`.